# How do I pipe logs from multiple linux instances over the network into one file?

Tags: linux

I have a shell script running on hundreds of linux machines that outputs a csv summary line at the end. I need to collect that into one file to review the summary of results. Is there a way to transfer that csv line over the network to one single machine that pipes them all to a single file?

Maybe something like a simple http server that append >> prints all input to a file and then the script can run a curl command to post it to that server?

Comment: Do you actually have an httpd daemon set up on each client machine? If not, you might consider something like [parallel ssh](http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/) although this could result in interleaving lines in the csv. Alternative might be `for host in $clients; do ssh $host cat /foo/bar.csv; done > aggregate.csv`. Possibly time consuming if you have thousands of hosts. Also assumes that you have pki authentication among hosts. Other alternative is if the hundreds of systems have a shared file system, put all of the csv's in a single directory and just `cat` into a single file.

Comment: It's many posting to one rather than one to many. I need the hundreds of instances running the script to be able to call back their output line at the end to the one instance that can then dump them to a single file together. Order is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution to have hundreds of systems ship an application's output back to a single would be to use `netcat`.

One the central server, put `netcat` into a infinite loop to receive input.

```
while true; do nc -l 4444; done | tee foo.csv
```

Then on each of the application hosts run

```
app.exe | nc foo.example.com 4444
```

Maybe not very robust but it would get the job done.

For a more reliable solution, set up `rsyslog` on the central server. Then on each of the app hosts use `logger --server foo.example.com "your message here"`. The messages posted through `logger` will be recorded in a file by `rsyslog` for further processing. Possibly more difficult to set up but easier in the long run.